# Bash/GitBash AWK get column values(from command output) by column name instead of column number

Tags: awk, filtering, multiple-columns, git-bash

I have [latest](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.0.windows.2) GitBash version installed and `$BASH_VERSION` is `4.4.23(1)`.

Now I am getting this output of command `ps aux` which is as here:

```
PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
<4-DIGITS>  <1-DIGIT>  <4-DIGITS>   <4-DIGITS>  ?   <5-DIGITS> <CURR_TIME> <COMMAND>
<4-DIGITS>  <1-DIGIT>  <4-DIGITS>   <4-DIGITS>  ?   <5-DIGITS> <CURR_TIME> <COMMAND>
....
....
<4-DIGITS>  <1-DIGIT>  <4-DIGITS>   <4-DIGITS>  ?   <5-DIGITS> <CURR_TIME> <COMMAND>
<4-DIGITS>  <1-DIGIT>  <4-DIGITS>   <4-DIGITS>  ?   <5-DIGITS> <CURR_TIME> <COMMAND>
```

From this output I want to be able to pull specific Column Values by just specifying Column Name(s)(could be multiple columns too) instead of everytime counting Columns from left-right for Column No.

I have this command but that only works for Files but I want this to work for another command's output as well:

```
awk -vcol=<COL_NAME> '(NR==1){colnum=-1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($(i)==col)colnum=i;}{print $(colnum)}'
```

How can I make this work for filtering previous command's output like `ps aux | awk <COLUMN_NAME=WINPID>` ?

Comment: No need to use `awk` or anything like that. `ps` can be instructed to output only certain columns using `ps -o ...`, see [`man ps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#OUTPUT_FORMAT_CONTROL).

Comment: Nah, I keep getting this error, atleast in GitBash when I try `ps` with `-o` or `-O` or `-o WINPID` etc. and some other combinations. `$ ps -O
ps: unknown option -- O
Try ``ps --help' for more information.`

Comment: Seems like the `ps` shipped with GitiBash is not POSIX conform. My bad. But [your awk command already works](https://onlinegdb.com/WiVMKgE1z). What else do you need?

Comment: It doesn't work with multiple columns, also I tried it yesterday it wasn't working, but could be I mistyped it, thanks for pointing it  out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `ps` output fields do not contain white space (eg, entries under `STIME` do not look like `Sep 27`)
- column name matches are case sensitive (this can be changed by adding `tolower()` calls)

Sample input file:

```
$ cat ps.out
PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
<4-DIGITS1>  <1-DIGIT1>  <4-DIGITS1>   <4-DIGITS1>  ?   <5-DIGITS1> <CURR_TIME1> <COMMAND1>
<4-DIGITS2>  <1-DIGIT2>  <4-DIGITS2>   <4-DIGITS2>  ?   <5-DIGITS2> <CURR_TIME2> <COMMAND2>
<4-DIGITS3>  <1-DIGIT3>  <4-DIGITS3>   <4-DIGITS3>  ?   <5-DIGITS3> <CURR_TIME3> <COMMAND3>
<4-DIGITS4>  <1-DIGIT4>  <4-DIGITS4>   <4-DIGITS4>  ?   <5-DIGITS4> <CURR_TIME4> <COMMAND4>
```

One idea using `awk`:

```
$ columns='WINPID'
$ awk -v cols="${columns}" '
BEGIN  { n=split(cols,arr,",")            # parse list of column names
         for (i=1;i<=n;i++) 
             headers[arr[i]]              # convert to associative array
       }
FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)              # for each field (aka column) header ...
             if ($i in headers)           # if it is in headers[] then ...
                fields[i]                 # keep track of the associated field #
       }
       { pfx=""
         for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {            # for each input field # ...
             if (i in fields) {           # if it is in fields[] then ...
                printf "%s%s", pfx, $i    # print the field (aka column)
                pfx=OFS
             }
         }
         printf "\n"                      # terminate the line
       }
' ps.out
```

This generates:

```
WINPID
<4-DIGITS1>
<4-DIGITS2>
<4-DIGITS3>
<4-DIGITS4>
```

With `columns='WINPID,UID'` we get:

```
WINPID UID
<4-DIGITS1> <5-DIGITS1>
<4-DIGITS2> <5-DIGITS2>
<4-DIGITS3> <5-DIGITS3>
<4-DIGITS4> <5-DIGITS4>
```

**NOTE:** OP can modify the `printf` formats to adjust the output as desired

---

To apply the `awk` script directly to the output of the `ps` (simulated via `cat ps.out`):

```
$ columns='PID,STIME,COMMAND'
$ cat ps.out | awk -v cols="${columns}" '
BEGIN  { n=split(cols,arr,",")
         for (i=1;i<=n;i++) 
             headers[arr[i]]
       }
FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
             if ($i in headers)
                fields[i]
       }
       { pfx=""
         for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
             if (i in fields) {
                printf "%s%s", pfx, $i
                pfx=OFS
             }
         }
         printf "\n"
       }
'
```

This generates:

```
PID STIME COMMAND
<4-DIGITS1> <CURR_TIME1> <COMMAND1>
<4-DIGITS2> <CURR_TIME2> <COMMAND2>
<4-DIGITS3> <CURR_TIME3> <COMMAND3>
<4-DIGITS4> <CURR_TIME4> <COMMAND4>
```